# A library/way that allows to have a master "template" and then specify its components in another file?

Tags: php, html, templates

I've used [Laravel Framework](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) before and really loved how you can have a master template that has everything and then you could put `@yield('content')` in one place and `@yield('sidebar')` in another and then in your actual PHP/HTML files you would say:

```
@extends('master')

@section('header')
    ** some additional header code **
@endsection

@section('content')
    ** php/html code here **
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
    ** php/html code here **
@endsection

@section('footer')
    ** some additional footer code and/or scripts here **
@endsection
```

And that's just an amazing way to handle things!
But I can't seem to find a way to do it in raw php (no framework involved) and was wondering whether there is a library that could help me achieve exactly that? Or better if it's actually possible to write it myself using raw php (as I don't actually need loads of unnecessary files and functionality that template engines provide)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably something like a template engine. Take a look at [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). It is mainly used in the Symfony framework, but afaik it can be used standalone as well.

It has a lot of other features, but the one you are looking for is [Twigs extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html).

From the documentation:

You can define a base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2011 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and template which extend this base template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
        Welcome on my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

You might need some time to get used to the syntax though...